# How to accumulate submatrices without looping (subarray smoothing)?

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, arrays

In Matlab I need to accumulate overlapping diagonal blocks of a large matrix. The sample code is given below.

Since this piece of code needs to run several times, it consumes a lot of resources. The process is used in array signal processing for a so-called subarray smoothing or spatial smoothing. Is there any way to do this faster?

```
% some values for parameters
M = 1000; % size of array
m = 400; % size of subarray
n = M-m+1; % number of subarrays 
R = randn(M)+1i*rand(M);

% main code
S = R(1:m,1:m);
for i = 2:n
    S = S + R(i:m+i-1,i:m+i-1);
end
```

ATTEMPTS:

1) I tried the following alternative vectorized version, but unfortunately it became much slower!

```
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:m);
inds1 = sub2ind([M,M],Y(:),X(:));
steps = (0:n-1)*(M+1);
inds = repmat(inds1,1,n) + repmat(steps,m^2,1);
RR = sum(R(inds),2);
S = reshape(RR,m,m);
```

2) I used Matlab coder to create a MEX file and it became much slower!

Answer (score -1):

I've personally had to fasten up some portions of my code lately. Being not an expert at all, I would recommend trying the following:

1) **Vectorize**:

Getting rid of the for-loop

```
S = R(1:m,1:m);
for i = 2:n
    S = S + R(i:m+i-1,i:m+i-1)
end
```

and replacing it for an alternative based on `cumsum` should be the way to go here.

*Note: will try and work on this approach on a future Edit*

2) **Generating a MEX-file**:

In some instances, you could simply fire up the [Matlab Coder app](http://ch.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) (given that you have it in your current Matlab version).
This should generate a `.mex` file for you, that you can call as it was the function that you are trying to replace.

---

Regardless of your choice (1) or 2)), you should profile your current implementation with `tic; my_function(); toc;` for a fair number of function calls, and compare it with your current implementation:

```
my_time = zeros(1,10000);
for count = 1:10000
    tic;
    my_function();
    my_time(count) = toc;
end
mean(my_time)
```

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I use matlab profiler to benchamrek the code and find bottlenecks. Generating a MEX-file is a good idea taht i did not think about it. Vectorizing the loop was my first intention, and I could not succeed yet. Functions like accumarray and cumsum were not useful. I can gerenate some of the indices using hankel(1:n,n:M) but it requires further work, e.g., using meshgrid, to create all the indices and may become even slower.

Comment: Hmmm, I underestimated the difficulty of vectorizing. Have you tried the MEX-file approach